# Array with Vlookup and Loop

Tags: vba

I am quite new in VBA, could you help me please?
I want to create an Array with 3 values: 2 dimensions

```
1 = Data
2 = Functions
3 = Other
```

and then in Excel if one of These 3 numbers, look with For Each or For Next to the Array and retrieve the strings, like
`for i = 1 to 20, if cells(i,1).Value = 1 or 2 or 3` then assign Strings..

MAny thanks for your help

Comment: `if cells(i,1).Value = 1 or cells(i,1).Value = 2 or cells(i,1).Value = 3`. You can possibly shorten it with a `Select` statement.

Comment: yes, but I have 120 numbers....wanted to find a solution with Array..

Answer (score 0):

You can pick up a 2-d array from a worksheet, and then use `Vlookup` on that:

```
Dim arr, m

arr = Range("G4:H6").Value

m = Application.VLookup(Range("G9"), arr, 2, False)

Range("H9") = IIf(IsError(m), "???", m)
```

If there's no match then `IsError(m)` will be `True`

EDIT: loading the array in code

```
Dim arr(1 to 3, 1 to 2), m

arr(1, 1) = 1
arr(1, 2) = "One"
arr(2, 1) = 2
arr(2, 2) = "Two"
arr(3, 1) = 3
arr(3, 2) = "Three"

m = Application.VLookup(Range("G9"), arr, 2, False)

Range("H9") = IIf(IsError(m), "???", m)
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answering...
the Problem is I don´t have Array in the worksheet. I have to create it in the script...and look up in this based on value in the worksheet.
lets say if a cell = 1 then it should go to created Array and assign value for 1 from the Array....

Comment: Finally....thank you very much indeed!
Now it look like:
Sub test()
Dim cell
Dim arr(1 To 3, 1 To 2), m

arr(1, 1) = 1: arr(1, 2) = "One"
arr(2, 1) = 2: arr(2, 2) = "Two"
arr(3, 1) = 2: arr(3, 2) = "Two"
For Each cell In Range("C9:C12")
cell = Application.VLookup(cell, arr, 2, False)
Next cell
cell = IIf(IsError(cell), "???", cell)

End Sub

Comment: If you want to share code then you should edit your question to add it - code in comments is too difficult to read...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that..
I modified a Little bit with Loop and it works, thanks

```
    Sub test()
Dim arr(1 To 3, 1 To 2), m

arr(1, 1) = 1: arr(1, 2) = "One"
arr(2, 1) = 2: arr(2, 2) = "Two"
arr(3, 1) = 3: arr(3, 2) = "Three"
For Each m In Range("C9:C12")
m.Value = Application.VLookup(m, arr, 2, False)

m = IIf(IsError(m), "???", m)
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

standing your array structure you coudl simplify your code as follows:

```
Sub test()
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim m As Range

    arr = Array("One", "Two", "Three")

    On Error Resume Next '<--| prevent possible out-of-array values to stop the code
    With Range("C9:C12") '<--| reference your relevant range
        For Each m In .Cells '<--| loop through its cells
            m.Value = arr(m - 1) '<--| an m.Value of 1 would point at the 0th (i.e.: the "first") position of the array 
        Next
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Value = "???" '<--| substitute "survived" numbers (i.e. out of array indexes) with "???"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

based on this code, how to add one more line
e.g.

```
1 = "One" = "OK"
2 = "Two" = "OK"
3 = "Three" = "Not OK"
```

so basically: 1 and 2 have 2 dimenstion and one super-Dimension

```
            Sub test()
Dim arr(1 To 3, 1 To 2), m

arr(1, 1) = 1: arr(1, 2) = "One"
arr(2, 1) = 2: arr(2, 2) = "Two"
arr(3, 1) = 3: arr(3, 2) = "Three"
For Each m In Range("C9:C12")
m.Value = Application.VLookup(m, arr, 2, False)

m = IIf(IsError(m), "???", m)
Next
End Sub
```